# Replace tag with special chars in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a xml file containing the xml header and xml footer and I want to remove the header and footer and store the content in a variable. The xml file's content changes inside a loop.

For example:

```
for (some range) do (
set "xmlHeader=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">"
set "xmlFooter=</Config>"

<then get and set variable from xml file>
)
```

The xml file contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
<tag1>info1 changes in the loop</tag1>
<tag2>info2 changes in the loop</tag2>
</Config>
```

And I want a variable in batch be storing

```
<tag1>info1</tag1>
<tag2>info2</tag2>
```

I've tried:

```
for (outer loop condition ) do (
for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%c in (xmlFile.xml) do set config=%%c
"!config:%xmlHeader%=!"
echo "!config!"
)
```

But the replace didn't do anything. Please help! Thank you.

Comment: Not very helpful, I know, but this is the kind of stuff [XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT) was invented for.

Comment: what is this: `changes in the loop` ?

Comment: Manipulating XML in batch is tricky. You can easily break your code with unexpected `"`, `<`, ... I use `xmlstarlet` (xmlstar.sourceforge.net) for XML manipulation in batch.

Comment: In this case, with xmlstarlet, `xml sel -t -c "/Config/node()" -n file.xml`

Comment: Answer to Endoro. Changes in the loop means this text will change within the for loop. This is not that impo
rtant to the text manipulation I am trying to do. So we can assume the string inside the tag is constant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try it with [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

example:

```
    >type file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="1.0">
    <tag1>info1 changes in the loop</tag1>
    <tag2>info2 changes in the loop</tag2>
    </Config>

    >sed -r "\#xml version|</Config>#d; s#^(<[^>]+>\S+)[^<]+(<[^>]+>)#\1\2#" file
    <tag1>info1</tag1>
    <tag2>info2</tag2>
```

Comment: Thanks again Endoro. This works for configs on different lines. How to do this when the input is on the same line for example:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config xmlns="http://address.com/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0"><tag1>info1 changes in the loop</tag1> <tag2>info2 changes in the loop</tag2>  </Config>

Comment: I've tried another way to use sed. this works on Linux but don't do anything on Windows: set "xmlHeader=<?xml version="1.0" ... ?>"  sed -e "s@%xmlHeader%@@g" -i.backup xmlFile.xml   any suggestions?

Comment: This wasn't the question. Please do not enhance questions. Make new ones.

Comment: I've posted a new question using sed at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17952175/xml-string-replacement-in-windows-batch-file

Comment: Thanks Endoro. I was hoping you would provide further inputs on the case when xml is all on one line. But I will accept the answer you've given that address the case when they are on different lines.

Answer (score 2):

#### Batch String Replacement

`%Var:Term=Replace%`

These are some rules you must follow when working with batch's string replacement

- The string to be replaced (the search term) may not contain any of the following characters

  - Equals sign `=` (Because this is how it knows the search term ends)
- The string to be replaced (the search term) may not begin with the following characters

  - Tilde `~` (Because this is a special character for batch strings)
  - Asterisk `*` (Because this is a special character for batch strings)

#### Solutions

See http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2710 by DBenham for a 100% batch solution.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/891976 by DBenham for a Batch/JScript hybrid solution.

See [https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/4608317](https://gist.github.com/DavidRuhmann/4608317/raw/53406e1b817badb7d266a6a76660379ff5480038/FindandReplace.bat) for a Proof of Concept of mine 100% batch.