# XML string replacement in Windows batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a xml file with header and footer like:

```
set "header=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config   xmlns="http://namespace.com/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">"
set "footer=</Config>"
```

I want to remove them from the xml file then read in the remaining items in between the header and footer tags.

I've tried to use sed. this works on Linux but don't do anything on Windows

```
sed -e "s@%header%@@g" -i.backup xmlFile.xml any suggestions?
```

Comment: you have different variables in your code: `header` and `xmlHeader`.

Comment: Changed to variables to be the same. This is not the problem though. Script still don't remove header from xml file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows you must escape double quotes with a backslash:

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
set "XMLheader=<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Config   xmlns=\"http://namespace.com/config\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"2.0\">"
set "footer=</Config>"
sed "s@%xmlHeader%\|%footer%@@g" file
```

Example on the command line:

```
    >type file
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Config   xmlns="http://namespace.com/config" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" version="2.0">
    <tag1>info1 changes in the loop</tag1>
    <tag2>info2 changes in the loop</tag2>
    </Config>

    >sed "s@<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><Config   xmlns=\"http://namespace.com/config\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" version=\"2.0\">\|</Config>@@g" file

    <tag1>info1 changes in the loop</tag1>
    <tag2>info2 changes in the loop</tag2>
```

Note: the `g` flag for the `s` command of `sed` is not necessary here.

Comment: Works great! Thanks Endoro!